# What are all the ways to get stardust in Pokémon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Anytime I caught Pokemon, it gave me 100 stardust. As far as I know, this is a set number you get regardless of what is being caught.  Also, I've yet to see another way to get stardust.

So, when I captured an Eevee today, I was confused by my stardust total.

[image: 5256 stardust]

Somehow I managed to get 5,256 stardust.  Since I've only ever noticed stardust increment in 100s, I'm guessing I missed something.  Are there other ways of getting stardust or am I wrong in thinking each successful capture always gives 100?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**As of September 2021:**

There are several ways to collect stardust.

1. The most common way is catching pokemon, which usually gives 100 stardust, but some pokemon (ex: Audino, Chimecho, Shroomish) will provide more stardust for each catch. Catching evolved pokemon provides more stardust depending on the number of times it's evolved, at a rate of 200 bonus dust per level of evolution (Pidgey is 100 stardust, Pidgeotto is 300, Pidgeot is 500). Weather boosted pokemon also provide a 25% boost to catch stardust (125 instead of 100, 375 instead of 300).
2. Hatching pokemon gives variable amounts of stardust, with 2 kilometer eggs giving a little (500-1000 stardust), 5 kilometer and 7 kilometer eggs giving a mid-range amount (fun fact: they have the same range, so 7 kilometer eggs are objectively worse when comparing stardust per kilometer), and the 10 and 12 kilometer eggs provide a large amount. When I say large amount, it still maxes out around 6k stardust from the 10 and 12 kilometer eggs, so it may not feel like a lot.
3. Feeding berries to gym defenders provides 30 stardust per berry, regardless of type of berry or who the pokemon belongs to, as long as the defender is the same team as you. You cannot feed defenders from a different team. This feature is capped by the fact that you can only feed 10 berries to a defender every half hour. Granted, this means you could get 1800 stardust from a full gym every half hour if you have more berries than you know what to do with. *Bonus*: there is also a small change of getting a candy from the defender you feed berries to.
4. Raid Battles provide stardust when completed. There is a small stardust reward if you fail to beat the raid pokemon, like 500 dust, and a larger amount if you win the raid. The amount of stardust if you win varies on the level of the raid, with level 5 raids providing 10k stardust. If you catch the pokemon after the raid, you get catch dust as well.
5. Battle matches against Team Go Rocket, Team Go Rocket leaders, and the Team leaders of Valor, Mystic, and Instinct provide stardust if you win. If you catch the shadow pokemon at the end of the battle with a member of Team Go Rocket, you also get the catch stardust.
6. Battle matches in the Go Battle League may provide some stardust, but not at the end of each battle. Currently, stardust is a reward for winning 1 match in a set of 5, and additional dust for winning all 5 matches in a set of 5. Upon completion of the set of 5 battles, you will be provided some stardust, where the amount varies based on your current rank and how many battles you won in the set. Winning more battles in a set means you get more stardust. If you select the Premium track instead of the Regular track for a set, your rewards will be larger amount of stardust, but it does cost a Premium Battle Pass. There is also a stardust reward at the end of the season (each season is three months) which provides an amount based on the rank you achieved. It can be a couple thousand stardust at lower ranks like 3 or 4, and 10k-20k if you get to higher ranks like 15.
7. **Added thanks to a comment from MBorg**: Some field research tasks and special research tasks provide stardust as a reward for completion. For field research this can range from 100-1000 stardust, usually depending if the research is from a sponsored stop. Special research tasks can provide many different amounts of stardust, usually depending on whatever theme or story the special research is following. Ex: Spiritomb special research would provide 108 stardust or 1080 stardust for rewards due to lore that the Pokemon being 108 spirits trapped in a keystone. The Research Breakthrough from getting seven stamps from field research also has a stardust reward, usually around 2000 stardust, and comes with a pokemon that provides catch dust as well.

**Extras**:

- The first catch of the day provides a large amount of bonus dust, currently it's an extra 1800 stardust. This bonus is increased to an extra 9000 stardust for the first catch of the day if it completes a "7 day streak". These numbers are just the bonus and do not include the catch dust itself.
- Using a star piece provides a general 50% boost to stardust you receive. This boost applies to nearly every sources of stardust, but there may be some exceptions I do not know about. I am sure it boosts catch stardust, raid reward stardust, and the "end of season" stardust reward. I'm unsure if it boosts stardust for feeding berries or for beating Team Go Rocket members. Using a star piece while using an incense is a great way to farm stardust by boosting the number of pokemon to catch while boosting the amount of stardust received from each catch.

**Note**:
Defending a gym no longer provides stardust, that was removed when the berry feeding feature was added.

Comment: You can also earn stardust from research task rewards, including special and limited time research. Also to note, in terms of egg stardust per distance, 12km eggs > 2km > 5km = 10km > 7km. 12km eggs give on average twice as much as 10km eggs

Comment: Thanks @MBorg, I had forgotten that research tasks can provide stardust.

Answer (score 14):

Via [PokemonGo DB](http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/06/stardust_4.html), it describes the three sources to obtain Stardust

> In Pokémon Go, Stardust can be collected by capturing wild Pokémon and hatching Eggs. Unlike Candy, which is used to Power Up and Evolve a Pokémon specific to its evolution line, Stardust can be used to Power Up any captured Pokémon.
>
> Players with defending Pokémon at a Gym, will get a 'Defender Bonus' and be rewarded with Stardust and Pokécoins

Comment: Feeding berries to defenders and battling in GBL will also award stardust

Comment: @Marsroverr This answer is way outdated, hence the bounty I added :) I posted this long before the updated gym system and battle leagues

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the date. @Kadima posted a wonderful updated answer

Answer (score 4):

There are three ways to get stardust:

1. Catching pokemon.(100 Stardust each catch)
2. Hatching pokemon.(random amount)
3. Gym defender bonus. (500 Stardust per 21 hours you hold a gym, can be recieved the first time immediately after you add your Pokemon to the gym)

Reference:
http://au.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/Stardust

Comment: Hatching pokemon is not mentioned in your source, but I will confirm that I have received stardust from hatching

Comment: @Wondercricket I used the two I can personally confirm as answers, I added the gym part as that was something I found but I have been unable to confirm that myself.

Comment: @Theyna I feel like there was an update that made it so evolved versions gave more when caught.  Or perhaps that's just candies.  If you can confirm and update your answer, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Hatching eggs provides you with stardust as well, and the amount isn't necessarily fixed. When you hatch your next egg, pay attention to the items you receive in the top-right. You'll get stardust and candy, and the stardust amount will likely be some amount that isn't a nice even number.

Comment: I had thought it was CP related.. but a 150 CP Psyduck hatched to give me 800 starfust, and a 80 CP Staryu hatched to give me 1256

Answer (score 0):

You get stardust from defending a gym, which is collected every 21 hours as long as you have at least one Pokémon in a gym.

Answer (score -1):

Some of the best ways to get stardust is to catch Pokémon that give an increased amount. For example, lookin at [this](https://pokemongohub.net/post/guide/pokemon-that-give-extra-stardust-on-catch/) site some of these Pokémon give extra stardust 500+ as opposed to the usual 100 for base Pokémon. Higher tier and weather boosted give more stardust as well.

Another good way is to utilize star shards, which increase stardust gains by 50% for 30 minutes. Everyday if you catch one Pokémon for a week, on the 7th day you will get noticeably a lot more stardust, and when you starshard before claiming you can get lots of stardust that way.

Finally, go battle is another great way, especially on x3 stardust nights. The starshard applies here as well, as well as go battle league end season rewards.