# What are good ways to farm stardust?

Tags: pokemon-go

It feels that stardust is my big bottleneck right now. Mostly because most activities give 1000 dust or less but when you spend dust, its sometimes 200-300k per shot.

So yeah, i'm stuck with a low source of dust and every time I need to do something, its with a huge cost.

So is there any way to 'get rich quick' with Stardust, or you are stuck farming a lot to get the stardust you need?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What are all the ways to get stardust in Pokémon Go?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/273910/143571)

Comment: This question gets right up to the line of opinion-based, and at best is situational depending on your inventory, what you like to do in game, and what you have around you with respect to stops and gyms. It might be better if the question is reworded to be specific, like "How to boost stardust gain?" or "What are strategies to increase stardust over a half hour period?" Some strategies require a large initial investment that will then payout over months of play, others require coins/items and only help for a short time.

Comment: He said, "is there any way to 'get rich quick' with Stardust?"  Obviously not opinion based at all.

Comment: The opinion part is that there are several ways of getting rich quick, but each depends on your play style.  A table of actions and stardust rewards would be a nice answer to the question linked by @Wrigglenite.

Comment: My question was more of an addon. Yes with the related I know all the ways that there is to get stardust, but what I was looking for was what were the best strategies to roll as much stardust as possible in the least amount of time. So related, but not the same IMO.

Comment: @Fredy31 I agree, but your question title definitely does not reflect that, so please edit it.

Answer (score -1):

Some of the best ways to get stardust is to catch Pokémon that give an increased amount. For example, lookin at [this](https://pokemongohub.net/post/guide/pokemon-that-give-extra-stardust-on-catch/) site some of these Pokémon give extra stardust 500+ as opposed to the usual 100 for base Pokémon. Higher tier and weather boosted give more stardust as well.

Another good way is to utilize star shards, which increase stardust gains by 50% for 30 minutes. Everyday if you catch one Pokémon for a week, on the 7th day you will get noticeably a lot more stardust, and when you starshard before claiming you can get lots of stardust that way.

Finally, go battle is another great way, especially on x3 stardust nights. The starshard applies here as well, as well as go battle league end season rewards.

Answer (score -1):

Catch a lot.

That's it, that's all there is to it. The world's best players are catching about 2200-2400 Pokemon a day, and if you can find the time to replicate even half of that you'll be drowning in stardust pretty quickly.

There's ways you can optimise this, such as running starpieces during double dust events or events with higher spawn rates (such as spotlight hours) where you can catch more Pokemon per hour, but there's definitely no trick for earning large amounts of stardust in a short period of time. It's all about grinding catches.